# c# trying to access something from another method

Tags: c#, ajax

i am new to this so hope u guys bear with me . i am trying to insert into database the URL directory of the filePathImage upon btnDone. 
Partial Codes:

```
  protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        EnsureDirectoriesExist();


        String filepathImage = (@"Images/Story/" +txtTitle.Text + "/" + e.FileName);


        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filepathImage));


    }

 protected void btnDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        act.ActivityName = dropListActivity.SelectedItem.Text;
        act.Title = txtTitle.Text;

        act.FileURL = filepathImage;

        daoStory.Insert(act);
        daoStory.Save();
    }
```

i got a problem with filePathImage in act.FileURL = AjaxFileUpload1.filePathImage; Any advise or solutions will be grateful

Comment: `AjaxFileUpload` does not have a property called `filePathImage`: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx#ctl00_SampleContent_Properties_HeaderPanel - what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: filePathImage is a filepath name that i have given.

Comment: i tried act.FileURL = filePathImage; ... can't work

Comment: What problem are you having? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: filePathImage does not exist in the current context in the BtnDone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below, when upload complete you can put your path in to session and take that session path when you needed.

```
protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{

  // your Code 
  Session["filepathImage"] = filepathImage ; // put the path in session variable 

}

protected void btnDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Session["filepathImage"]!=null)
    {
         string filepathImage = Session["filepathImage"] as string;
         // your code ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works ! but i've got another question , duno if its appropriate to ask here . i am going to save the URL directory to database by : 
String filepathImage = (@"Images/Story/" +txtTitle.Text + "/" + e.FileName);

However in the database , it doesn't not take into account of txtTitle.Text ... it appears as Images/Story//Jellyfish.jpg in DB